# Comparing dates in MVC 4 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to compare due date with current date but its not working as expected i have tried in following ways but in working

`cmp` Always return 1
  `test1`,`test2` and `test` are always false

```
 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(data.DueDate.ToShortDateString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
 DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
 var test1 = dt1.Date == dt2.Date;
 var test2 = dt1.Date <= dt2.Date;
 var test=  Convert.ToDateTime(data.DueDate).Date == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today).Date;
  int cmp = dt1.CompareTo(dt2);
```

I am writting my code in frontend view with razor .I searched on internet but none of given solution worked for me.How can i compare dates is there some other way for doing this or i'd tried all of them

Comment: Are you sure your `data.DueDate` and `DateTime.Today` are the same? Based your code, looks like `data.DueDate` is bigger than `DateTime.Today`. That's why it is _normal_ to return `cmp` is bigger than zero and `false` for others. BTW, since they are _already_ `DateTime`, you don't need to use `Convert.ToDateTime` with them.

Comment: Why are you converting `DateTime` values to strings and then converting them back to `DateTime`? What are you trying to compare?

Comment: yes i have two values for comparing 25 Oct and 29 Oct to compare with today

Comment: Why can't you use `if(data.DueDate <=DateTime.Today)`

Comment: It just needs to be `bool isEqual = data.DueDate.Date == DateTime.Today;` (or `bool isInFuture = data.DueDate.Date > DateTime.Today` or `bool isOverDue - data.DueDate.Date < DateTime.Today`)